# Create a VB6 dll using Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vb6

I have a windows form application created in Visual Studio.

I have referenced a COM API and I am trying to run this

```
L_RESULT = Visualfiles.SystemScript("HIST-TEL", sampleVisualBasicColl, "")
```

The second parameter needs to bee a collection, so I created this

```
    Dim sampleVisualBasicColl As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()

    Dim item1, item2, item3, item4 As String
    item1 = "Items"
    item2 = "In"
    item3 = "A"
    item4 = "Collection"
    sampleVisualBasicColl.Add(item1, "firstkey")
    sampleVisualBasicColl.Add(item2, "secondkey")
    sampleVisualBasicColl.Add(item3, "thirdkey")
    sampleVisualBasicColl.Add(item4, "fourthkey")
```

But the error that I get is this

Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection' to type 'VBA.Collection'.

I have found this article which I think will help - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/323737

But how do I complete steps 1-4?

I have visual studio community 2015 and I am not sure how to create this dll?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: We should not have to leave this site to figure out what you're asking. Please include the **relevant information** here, in your question itself. If the content is off-site, and that off-site location is unavailable (off-line, moved (which yes, happens at MS also), or deleted), your question has no value for future readers here. (And if you read the error message, you'll see it's looking for a VBA.Collection, which is not VB6 - it's Visual Basic for Applications, which is used in Excel, Word, and other Office applications. VB6 is an old, no longer supported separate IDE and language.)

Comment: ok sorry Ken! What I am trying to do is create a Create a Visual Basic 6.0 Microsoft ActiveX DLL project which the MS article recommends I do. But I don't understand how to do this? I have Visual Studio 2015. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Note that the article is talking about an 11 year old product and an 18 year old one.  It also does not even say you can use VS2005 to create the VB6 DLL

Comment: As I said, VB6 is no longer supported. You **cannot** create a VB6 DLL in anything but VB6, and VB6 is long dead. Find another way.

Comment: Actually VB6 is supported.  New development is discouraged by the forces holding Microsoft in thrall these days, and the IDE/compiler get only minimal support (hardly even security bugs get fixed), but VB6 is still the backbone of Windows for many shops. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx

Answer (score 9):

The Collection coclass is a chronic trouble-maker, Microsoft created too many implementations of it.  And, quite unwisely, gave those implementations the same CLSID.  Not that clear how this went so badly wrong, probably one group of programmers not talking to another group.  The lousy solution they came up with was to force everybody to apply the [noncreatable] attribute.

Which stops you from adding a reference to, say, vba7.dll so you can create your own Collection object.  Which is why the KB article tells you to use VB6 to create an instance of the object.  Well, ugh, 18 years is a lot of dog lives and who has VB6 installed anymore today.  You need an MSDN license or good luck at an Ebay auction.

Time to get this fixed the correct way instead of that lousy KB way.  All you have to do is to create a concrete instance of the Collection object's default interface.  By COM rules, the implementation of the interface never matters.

Add a new class to your project and paste this code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace VBA    
    <ComVisible(True), Guid("A4C46780-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB")>
    Public Interface _Collection
        <DispId(0)> Function Item(<[In]> ByRef Index As Object) As Object
        <DispId(1)> Sub Add(<[In]> ByRef Item As Object, ByRef Optional Key As Object = Nothing,
                        ByRef Optional Before As Object = Nothing,
                        ByRef Optional After As Object = Nothing)
        <DispId(2)> Function Count() As Integer
        <DispId(3)> Sub Remove(<[In]> ByRef Index As Object)
        <DispId(-4)> Function _NewEnum() As IEnumerator
    End Interface

    '' <ComVisible(True)>
    <ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB")>
    Public Class Collection
        Implements _Collection
        Private impl As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection

        Public Sub Add(ByRef Item As Object, ByRef Optional Key As Object = Nothing, ByRef Optional Before As Object = Nothing, ByRef Optional After As Object = Nothing) Implements _Collection.Add
            impl.Add(Item, CStr(Key), Before, After)
        End Sub

        Public Sub Remove(ByRef Index As Object) Implements _Collection.Remove
            If TypeOf Index Is String Then impl.Remove(CStr(Index)) Else impl.Remove(CInt(Index))
        End Sub

        Public Function Count() As Integer Implements _Collection.Count
            Return impl.Count
        End Function

        Public Function _NewEnum() As IEnumerator Implements _Collection._NewEnum
            Return impl.GetEnumerator()
        End Function

        Public Function Item(ByRef Index As Object) As Object Implements _Collection.Item
            Return impl(Index)
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

So instead of creating a new Collection object, now create a new VBA.Collection object to keep the component happy.  I don't have a good way to test it anymore, hope it works.

Comment: Thanks Hans for this great suggestion, I did find something similar and try it, which didnt work. I've trued your suggestion but I get this error - Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'ClassLibrary2.VBACollection' to type 'VBA.Collection'. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Bummer, doctoring the interop library to change the argument type to the interface type would be necessary.  Talk to your supervisor, you need an MSDN subscription.  Good to have.

Comment: I know its so frustrating! it is just a small thing I am trying to do which will complete my project and will be a great application for everyone to use as it links two of our systems together and saves lots of time. I've spoken to my supervisor but cannot afford the MSDN subscription. Is there anyway you could help me to create the small dll in the MS article? I would be so grateful! Thank you

Comment: Try EBay instead, there is a full copy of VB6 there for US $270 at the moment. Disclaimer: other auction sites exist, I am not connected with the seller in any way myself.

Comment: Wrong approach.  The MSDN subscription costs about a week's worth of salary of a programmer.  If it is "too expensive" then you are too expensive by a factor of 52.  It is just a standard brush-off from a supervisor that doesn't want to fill out the paperwork.  Always aim high to make it worth his time, ask for the Universal edition.  And it will make him feel good when he negotiates you down to the edition you need.

Comment: ok thanks, would this do what I need it to do? Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise Edition. Or is it visual basic 6 I need?

Comment: Hi, I was able to create the dll in the MS article using VB6 and this solved my problem, I hope this hels someone in the future!